# C++ Write Memory Function vs. Pointer

Tags: c++

What's the difference between using a memory writing function like `WriteProcessMemory` and a pointer to write to memory? Say I had this address `0x12345`, and I wanted the byte at that address to be `0x15`. I could do this:

```
*(unsigned char*)0x12345 = 0x15;
```

and I could do this:

```
unsigned char data = 0x15;
WriteProcessMemory(handle,(LPVOID)pointer, &data, sizeof(data), NULL);
```

What is the advantage of one over the other?

Comment: The first is undefined behavior. The second is something specific to your OS.

Comment: Well, for one it seems that `WriteProcessMemory` allows you to write an entire block instead of a single byte. Secondly, I suspect that `0x12345` does not refer to another process' memory as in principle every process can address all of the available memory.

Comment: @SergeyA Isn't the first use *implementation-defined* behavior?

Comment: @MargaretBloom, nope. Undefined behavior clear and simple. `Indirection through an invalid pointer value and
passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior`.

Comment: @SergeyA Is't an *invalid pointer* implementation-defined? "*[...] mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined.
Except as described in 3.7.4.3, the result of such a conversion will not be a safely-derived pointer value.*" and "*It is implementation defined whether an implementation has relaxed or strict pointer safety.*"

Comment: @MargaretBloom, interesting point. I never thought about it. Looks like you are correct - implementations may choose that non safely-derived pointers are still not invalid pointer values. Good catch!

Comment: Why undefined behavior? In *good ol' days*, almost all interaction with hardware was done by writing to/reading from predefined memory addresses.

Comment: @el.pescado, good ol' days are over. The world has changed. It'll never be the same.

Comment: @bipll That's disingenuous. Even the most up-to-date compilers will behave appropriately when you access memory mapped peripherals that way. There's much to be said for progress in C++, but this particular issue isn't an example of "progress".

Comment: @MargaretBloom, in other words, it is implementation-defined whether such a store is undefined behaviour. :D

Comment: @bipll ever heard of, say, microcontrollers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the advantage of one over the other?

Pointers are specified by the C++ standard and supported by all implementations, while `WriteProcessMemory` is windows specific and not portable.

The two ways are quite different things. Assigning to a dereferenced pointer writes a single byte, while `WriteProcessMemory` allows writing arbitrary number of bytes. If need a standard way to copy multiple bytes starting from an address, see `std::memcpy`.

Another major difference is that `WriteProcessMemory` allows you to write to the memory of another process. There is no standard way to do that in C++. Processes are something that an operating system provides and the C++ standard does not specify how to interact with them.

TL;DR If you're simply writing to the memory of the current process itself, then you shouldn't use `WriteProcessMemory`.

Answer (score 0):

By C++ standard, pointer is not necessarily an (flat) address. I think taking pointer outside of array (or allocation) or one-past-end or nullptr is undefined behavior (or at least platform dependent).

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using your first implementation. This can give undefined behaviors. The second function you have presented is a Windows specific function and this is the one you should be using. Keep in mind that this application will not be cross platform.

If you want to do the same on a different platform you will have to adapt your code. For example on a Linux system you will be using process trace library:

> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html